# URL and URI difference when accessing web service in Java

Tags: java, php, web-services

I'm accessing a web service. Below is my PHP code which works perfectly fine:

```
class fNewRequest {
    function fNewReq($pTK, $pVID) 
    {
        $this->pTK= $pTK;
        $this->pVID= $pVID;
    }
}

/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("http://**.**.**.*/**/**/***/webservice.asmx?WSDL");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
  "pTK" => "asa",
  "pVID" => "1134",
);

/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: Function1 */
$response = $client->__soapCall("fNewRequests", array($params));

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);

print_r($params);
```

I am now trying to do the same with Java. Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;


public class ws1
{
      public static void ws1()
      {
            try
            {
             SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
             SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
             String url = "http://**.**.**.*/**/**/***/webservice.asmx?WSDL";
             SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
             printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
      }

      private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        String serverURI = "http://**.**.**.*/**/**/***/webservice.asmx?WSDL";

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsdl", serverURI);

        SOAPBody soapBody1 = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElemX = soapBody1.addChildElement("fNewRequests", "wsdl");

        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("pTK", "wsdl");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("asa");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("pVID", "wsdl");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("1134");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("performRecharge", serverURI + "performRecharge");
        System.out.println("");
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        return soapMessage;
    }

    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           ws1();
    }
}
```

I get back this:

```
Response SOAP Message = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode> 
     <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
     </faultstring>
     <detail/>
   </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I don't know what value to put for the URL and URI? Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is where you send your request to. The URI is the XML namespace that your body message must have (which can be also be an URL since [an URL is an URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier)).

You also must make sure you send the `SOAPAction` HTTP header (I see in the fault you get that the server complained about it).

Don't know what's in your WSDL so I'm going to explain using an online web service who's description can be found here: http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL.

In order to call this web service I need to send a request to http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx. From the WSDL I know the structure of the request and I know what namespace to use for the elements: `http://www.webserviceX.NET/`. Also from the WSDL I know the `SOAPAction` to send: `http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertTemp`.

So here is how the code might look like:

```
package com.test;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx";
        SOAPMessage request = Main.createSOAPRequest();

        System.out.print("Request: ");
        request.writeTo(System.out);

        SOAPMessage response = soapConnection.call(request, url);

        System.out.print("\nResponse: ");
        response.writeTo(System.out);
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertTemp");

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.addNamespaceDeclaration("prefix", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/");

        SOAPElement convertTempElement = soapBody.addChildElement("ConvertTemp", "prefix");

        SOAPElement temperatureElement = convertTempElement.addChildElement("Temperature", "prefix");
        temperatureElement.addTextNode("100");

        SOAPElement fromUnitElement = convertTempElement.addChildElement("FromUnit", "prefix");
        fromUnitElement.addTextNode("degreeCelsius");

        SOAPElement toUnitElement = convertTempElement.addChildElement("ToUnit", "prefix");
        toUnitElement.addTextNode("degreeFahrenheit");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```

The program sends this request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:prefix="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
        <prefix:ConvertTemp>
            <prefix:Temperature>100</prefix:Temperature>
            <prefix:FromUnit>degreeCelsius</prefix:FromUnit>
            <prefix:ToUnit>degreeFahrenheit</prefix:ToUnit>
        </prefix:ConvertTemp>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And gets back this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ConvertTempResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
            <ConvertTempResult>212</ConvertTempResult>
        </ConvertTempResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Compare this example with what you have and you will figure out what values to use.